# Decision tree : train() method parameters caret package

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cart, caret

I am working on a UCI repository's data set. I tried implementing a decision tree in the R programming language using the `caret` package.

```
trctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)
set.seed(3333)
dtree_fit <- train(V7 ~., data = training, method = "rpart",
                   trControl = trctrl,
                   tuneLength = 10)
dtree_fit$finalModel
```

Its giving 80% accuracy when tested on a test set.

Now, I want to implement some variations like changing the splitting method to information gain (I read that `rpart` uses Gini as its default splitting function).

To do this, I read the documentation by typing `?rpart`. But it showed this only:

```
parms   
optional parameters for the splitting function.
Anova splitting has no parameters.
Poisson splitting has a single parameter, the coefficient of variation of the prior distribution on the rates. The default value is 1.
Exponential splitting has the same parameter as Poisson.
For classification splitting, the list can contain any of: the vector of prior probabilities (component prior), the loss matrix (component loss) or the splitting index (component split). The priors must be positive and sum to 1. The loss matrix must have zeros on the diagonal and positive off-diagonal elements. The splitting index can be gini or information. The default priors are proportional to the data counts, the losses default to 1, and the split defaults to gini.
```

Can someone suggest, how can I change my splitting function in this snippet?

Please suggest some other variations which I can do to improve my model? (help me by sharing little bit of code snippets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can pass parameters to underlying models using caret.

```
dtree_fit <- train(V7 ~., data = training, method = "rpart",
                   trControl=trctrl,
                   tuneLength = 10, 
                   parms=list(split='information'))
```

Comment: thanks @danielson, can you suggest some other variations which I can do to improve my model?